# Close popup appears partially offscreen

Tags: bug

On my 13" MacBook Pro in the latest Chrome (yes,I cleared browser cache), the Close popup appears partially offscreen:

[image]

And, when I scroll down, I still can't pick a close reason:

[image]

I can't currently close questions as a result.

Comment: Last time I voted to close on a 13" MacBook Pro was on Friday, but I didn't face this issue. However, I maximized Chrome's window. From the screenshot, it looks like the window is smaller?

Comment: @AndrewT. The window was fairly big, but not maximized or fullscreen.  You can drag if you grab onto the popup title.  It looks like this is a known issue that will be fixed soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a know network-wide issue that is being fixed soon, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333092/close-question-dialog-half-off-screen-when-called-from-flag-handling-interface